# Remove all tr elements unless tr>td>input has a class 'DontRemoveMe'

Tags: css

Sorry for the very specific title, couldn't think of how to say it in more general terms.

Assume you have a table and each row contains a cell that has an input, but some input fields have a class of 'DontRemoveMe'. How do you target every row except the 'DontRemoveMe' rows?

Comment: CSS doesn't look up the tree, only down it. You'll need JavaScript to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulation of DOM Elements requires JavaScript. One way to achieve this is with jQuery:

```js
function remove() {
  $('tr:not(.dontRemoveMe)').remove();
}
```

```css
.dontRemoveMe td {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dontRemoveMe">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jon</td>
    <td>Jones</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="remove()">Remove rows</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS (Not Yet Implemented):**

Using CSS [level 4 selectors](http://css4.rocks/), I believe it would be

`tr:has(td>input:not(>>.DontRemoveMe))`

However, those aren't implemented in any browser. So you would want to use javascript.

**Javascript:**

```js
// Select all rows that don't contain a input.DontRemoveMe
let rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).filter(x => !(x.querySelector("input.DontRemoveMe")));

// Add a special class to these rows so we can target them with CSS
rows.forEach(x => x.classList.add("selected"));
```

```css
td {
  padding: 8px; /* Padding for all rows to make background visible */
}
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="selected" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="DontRemoveMe" type="text" value="not selected" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="selected" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old school javascript way.

Find all the `tr` tags then find any children with class `DontRemoveMe`, if it doesn't find any add a `.hide` class to the current row.

But, honestly I'd question the reason you want to do it like this, chances are there is a more sensible way.

```js
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

var i = 0;
var length = tr.length
for (; i < length; i++) {
  var dontRemove = tr[i].getElementsByClassName('DontRemoveMe')
  if (!dontRemove.length) {
    tr[i].classList.add('hide')
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  color: #ededed;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff3030;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #6495ED;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="red">
    <td>Normal</td>
    <td>Normal</td>
    <td class="DontRemoveMe">Don't Remove Me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blue">
    <td>Can't see me</td>
    <td>Can't see me</td>
    <td>Can't see me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="red">
    <td class="DontRemoveMe">Don't Remove Me</td>
    <td>Normal</td>
    <td class="DontRemoveMe">Don't Remove Me</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```